# Difference between try catch and NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: ios, iphone, exception, nsexception

I have tried two methods for catching the exceptions. First one is with a try catch and the second one is with the following code in Appdelegate.

```
void onUncaughtException(NSException* exception)
{
//save exception details
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&onUncaughtException);
}
```

The advantage of the second method is we don need to implement try catch blocks in each and every method.
The first one catches the exception, prints it but **does not crash the application**.. But the second one catches the exception and **crashes the application**. 
 Is there any way to use the second method to catch exceptions without crashing the application.

Answer (score 5):

`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` Sets the top-level error-handling function where you can perform last-minute logging before the program terminates. in the `onUncaughtException` you can do something before crash, but app do crash finally.

`@try...@catch...@finally..` is to try to catch possible NSException, if catch, run in the `@catch` block code, no matter if catch, code will run in `@finally` block code.  Using `@try...@catch...` will not cause crash finally, this may be the main difference.